# Scale for Shapes and Drawing Canvas are Different

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, canvas, shapes

I am using a `ZoomableCanvas` to show position of a vehile while driving. For this I use scale Factor as shown below

```
  double xq = this.drawingCanvas.ActualWidth / maxX; // The maximum X 
  double yq = this.drawingCanvas.ActualHeight / maxY; // The maximum Y
  // use the smallest proportion quotient
  GlobalVar.DrawingQ = xq < yq ? xq : yq;
```

This is used for showing the Map and scaling all the Points and Important location in he Map. All the Points (Locations) shown on Map are in X and Y co-ordinate.
To show a vehicle i use a `Windows.Shapes.Rectangle`. I know the Length and width of Vehicle hence I assign rectangle in the below shown way

```
double LenScaled = Length * GlobalVar.DrawingQ;
double WidthScaled = Width * GlobalVar.DrawingQ;
// Vehicle
Rectangle _rectangle = new Rectangle();
_rectangle.Width = LenScaled;
_rectangle.Height = WidthScaled;
```

Please note that the Co-ordinates of Points and the dimensions of Vehicle are in same unit but somehow the scaling is not correct. The Vehicle Appears to be bigger (it can be easily confirmed visually, but I am not showing a screen shot). Could you please provide your input.

Comment: Why not use a proper map control, where you can set vehicle positions in geographic coordinates, and give object sizes in real-world units, i.e. meters?

Comment: @Clemens I am not aware of `proper map control` and also, I am working on a pre-existing project rather than making a new one.